# Windows 7 won't boot past starting windows screen / stuck on Classpnp.sys in safe mode

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 stuck on CLASSPNP.SYS](https://superuser.com/questions/60810/windows-7-stuck-on-classpnp-sys)

I'm having trouble with my Windows 7 machine
It was fine, until this morning, when, for no reason what so ever, it decided not to boot past the "Starting Windows" screen
No hardware has been installed / removed.

I tried to boot into Safe mode, but it got stuck on classpnp.sys

I tried to do a recovery - by booting on to the windows 7 dvd... This did not work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: If it turns out the answers in the other question don't help you, edit your question and explain why your question is different and flag it for moderator attention, so it can be reopened

Answer (score 0):

I would begin by unplugging everything non-necessary.  If there is a plug-n-play device that is going bad it might be causing a problem.  Also unhook things like Cd-Rom and floppy drives drives internally, as I've heard of that fixing issues like this.

Also note that used to when windows was booting and would get stuck, the last thing listed was what it last successfully loaded, so it was whatever comes next that you can't see that was the issue.  I don't know if that is still the case though.