# Windows 7 stuck at loading screen during installation

Tags: windows-7

A first, my laptop with windows 7 64bit stucks at the loading windows screen. Same with safe mode. The files are scrolling down then it stucks at:

```
windows\system32\drivers\CLASSPNP.sys
```

Tried it multiple times and it gets stuck there multiple times.

When I try to boot from a usb (windows 7 64bit), it loads the files and stuck at the same loading screen as before.

So the only clue here I have so far is stucking at that CLASSPNP.sys file. But I dont get why it would when booting from a USB. I can still see the windows loading animations so the PC did hang.

Any tips?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 7 won't boot past starting windows screen / stuck on Classpnp.sys in safe mode](http://superuser.com/questions/106851/windows-7-wont-boot-past-starting-windows-screen-stuck-on-classpnp-sys-in-saf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One suggestion, is if you have access to say... a Linux liveCD or perhaps a Hiren's CD with an "Mini" OS on it to boot from and see how that works.  If all is good I would lean towards some kind of corruption of your system files AND potentially that USB Drive as well (where/when did you make it?  Any possibility at all it's not pristine to use?  You can also make a Hiren's bootable USB Key so I might try one of those... or perhaps also a Linux one http://www.backtrack-linux.org/tutorials/usb-live-install/ is one that I like).  I still would go with a CD first then try a USB just for giggles to see how they both react.  Another choice is to try and boot a Windows installation CD/DVD.  You don't have to proceed obviously but see if it can detect your existing installation and if you have a backup... you could even give Windows Repair a shot.  I tend to have some pretty good luck with it at the Office.

Comment: Gosh another thought I forgot was to try Windows Safe Command Prompt.  I have had luck with that a few times when both normal and safe mode failed and I wanted to a system file check (sfc /scannow).  If it's corruption of a DLL file or a SYS file, this has a good shot of fixing it.