# Windows 7 x64 Pro Black Screen of Death - Tried Multiple Solutions, Stuck

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

We recently started receiving the black screen of death on a computer that stores sensitive credit card data for a restaurant.  Basically the computer makes it past it's regular boot screen, then goes to black, with a cursor.  This happens in all bootup modes, including VGA modes, Safe Modes, Last Know Good Config, and Disable auto reboot. The encryption key is tied to the hardware of the PC, so we are seriously running out of options with stuck transactions on it.  I have read through multiple posts, Googled, and worked on it for 8 hours to no avail.  Here is what I tried so far:

1. Attempedt Repair my Computer from Windows 7 DVD (with every version of Windows 7 x86 and x64 on it (Option was not available at Safe Mode Menu, Requested DVD).  Received error: This version of System Recovery Options is not compatible with the version of Windows.  Also attempted changing every BIOS setting no fix.  Computer is running on a Lenovo PC with a re-installed OS.
2. Attempted same thing with Windows 10 from DVD.  Received same error.  Attempted bootrec.exe /fixmbr, /fixboot, /rebuildbcd no fix.
3. Attempted a chkdsk using Hirens 15.2 .  No errors found.
4. Attempted to disable all drives using Hirus's startup selector.  Disabled everything but "Fastboot.sys" a Lenovo driver (that caused blue screens when removed), and Intel USB 3 drivers, (also caused blue screens when removed).  Replaced both drivers, no fix.
5. Tried to pull logs from the computer, but they were corrupted upon opening them on another Windows 7 PC.
6. Attempted switch from onboard graphics card, to a PCI-E Graphics Card again no fix.
7. Attempted upgrade to Windows 10, not possible because can't login to Windows.
8. Attempted malware scan using MalwareBytes on Hiren. Clear.
9. Attempted Easy Recovery Essentials, no fix.
10. Attempted to connect via RDP.  No success.
11. Attempted Windows Boot Genius, No Fix.
12. Placed hard drive in another computer, wouldn't even boot.

The safe mode stops at ClassPNP.sys . Not sure if thats ok or not.  Basically, I can't get into recovery, I have disabled all drivers except for 4.  Tried everything I could find on the internet.  Basically we just need to be able to log in once, connected to the internet, click 3 buttons and can then reformat.  Anything else left I can try.  Is there anyway to force an upgrade, or a reformat that will work like a regular Windows 7 upgrade?  Thanks.

Comment: Not really a dupe, but also stuck at ClassPNP.sys, suggests sfc /scannow if you can get to it, or replacing it with an older version - http://superuser.com/questions/60810/windows-7-stuck-on-classpnp-sys

Comment: "the computer makes it past it's regular boot screen, then goes to black, with a cursor" - can you post a picture ? Or explain better ? At which point exactly does the cursor appear ? Immediately after boot screen or after a while, after starting to load the OS ?

Comment: @tetsujin, I'll try replacing classpnp.sys

Comment: @overmind It looks as though everything is fine when it passes the typical windows 7 pre-login logo (with the exception of it having a green loding bar like vista, instead of a windows logo thing like 7) and then right before it displays "welcome" or the login prompt, it goes to black.

Comment: Buncha questions: What encryption have you used?  You say logs are corrupt; is other data easily accessible?  Or is the only encrypted data something related to the credit card software?  You seem to have done a lot of changes for a system that you can't even boot.  You did most of this when booted off of other media?  Are you only having problems when using the network?  You say you can't RDP.  Can you ping?  Use RPC (e.g. CompMgmt)?  WMI (e.g., WMIC /node:hostname MemoryChip GET)?  Can you create a new user and then try logging into the new user's profile?  On a domain?  Data backed up?